# How many hours I worked per week?

Tags: rates

How can I answer this question (How many hours you worked per week) for my insurance application, if I worked on call, as an interpreter? Sometimes I had an assignment for 2 hours once a week, sometimes more, sometimes I didn't have on call assignment at all during a month.

Comment: Did you ask the insurance company? I don't think there is any way someone here could possibly know the answer to that.

Comment: @JohnFx It's unemployment insurance. Nobody picks up the phone.

Comment: Location may be required for this. If you are an independent contractor the laws of your jurisdiction may limit your eligibility for unemployment insurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Average it out and give the most accurate answer you can.

Comment: +1 - right, but I believe the most important thing is to disclose the amount of money earned. As I recall, the unemployment benefit is reduced based on earnings. But not eliminated for relative small amounts. They encourage you to work.